# appendChild to h2 class

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I was hoping to appendChild to my h2 class.  I would like to be able to stick the value from my innerHTML into the end of the h2.  My error message is cannot read property of appendChild of Null.

```js
function selectMeds(element) {
    //when you set the variable to element, it enables you to onclick on the thises instead of when you getElementbyId and it only finds the first one
    let checkBox = element;
    //    let checkBox = document.getElementById("medType");
    //    let text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        let hiddenMed = document.querySelector('.questionMed');
        hiddenMed.classList.remove("hidden");
        let medName = checkBox.value;
        let hiddenMedQ = document.querySelector("hiddenQ");
        hiddenMedQ.appendChild(medName);

    } else {
        let hiddenMed = document.querySelector('.questionMed');
        hiddenMed.classList.add("hidden");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container question questionMed hidden">
        <h2 class="hiddenQ">Did you need a refill of </h2>
        <select class="form-control" id="medAmount">
                <option>Select an Option</option>
                <option>Yes</option>
                <option>No</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: When is `selectMeds` called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `document.querySelector("hiddenQ");` with `document.querySelector(".hiddenQ");` because `hiddenQ` is a class and you need `.hiddenQ` in the `querySelector`. Thus, your `if` condition will have this block of code

```
if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    let hiddenMed = document.querySelector('.questionMed');
    hiddenMed.classList.remove("hidden");
    let medName = checkBox.value;
    let hiddenMedQ = document.querySelector(".hiddenQ");
    hiddenMedQ.appendChild(medName);
}
```

Here is an illustration of something which you are tying to achieve:

```js
let hiddenMed = document.querySelector('.questionMed');
let hiddenMedQ = document.querySelector(".hiddenQ");
var initialH2 = hiddenMedQ.innerHTML;
function selectMeds(element) {
  let checkBox = element;
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      hiddenMed.classList.remove("hidden");
      let medName = checkBox.value;
      hiddenMedQ.innerHTML = initialH2 +medName;

  } else {
      let hiddenMed = document.querySelector('.questionMed');
      hiddenMed.classList.add("hidden");
      hiddenMedQ.innerHTML = initialH2;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container question questionMed hidden">
  <h2 class="hiddenQ">Did you need a refill of </h2>
  <select class="form-control" id="medAmount">
          <option>Select an Option</option>
          <option>Yes</option>
          <option>No</option>
  </select>
</div>
    
<input type="checkbox" class="medType" onclick="selectMeds(this)" value="Tylenol"><label>Tylenol</label>
```

Comment: This is getting me much closer!  The only issue is that it doesn't add the medication name to the h2.                                                                           <label><input type="checkbox" class="medType" onclick="selectMeds(this)" value="Tylenol">Tylenol</label>

Comment: @JaneWheatley check the updated answer. It will add the name to h2

Comment: @JaneWheatley glad to help you

Comment: So this worked wonderfully, but now I'm realizing I actually need a new and different dropdown with question for every checkbox that is checked.  So if I selected two different meds, then two dropdowns would appear.  I suppose I can't use the hidden method anymore, but need to append.  How would you go about doing this with dropdowns?  Thank you!!!!